# Not identifying a method called from header to main C++?

Tags: c++, class, methods

I defined a class in a header file and declared the functions in it and made the function body in a seperate cpp file. Then it was not identified in main. I have reviewed a lot of questions and some used the word static in the declaration but when I tried it the function was re declared so it did nothing and I made sure the the header file was included in both cpp files yet it still doesn't recognize it.

#Login and registration system.cpp#

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "L&S functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (status == 1) {
        Login();   // this shows an error
        cout << "Login";
    }
    else if (status == 2) {
        Register();  // this shows an error
        cout << "Register";
    }
}
```

#L&S functions.h#

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class User {
    string username;
    string password;
    string mail;

public:
     void Register(); 
     void Login();


};
```

#L&S functions.cpp#

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "L&S functions.h"
using namespace std;

vector<User> people;                               // initiating vector "people" of type "User"

void User::Register() {
    User person;                                  // instantiating a user

    cout << "Please choose your username: ";
    cin >> User.username;                         // adds username
    cout << "\nPlease set your password: ";
    cin >> User.password;                        // adds password
    cout << "\nPlease set your email: ";
    cin >> User.mail;                           // adds email
    cout << "\nRegistered successfully!";
    people.pushback(person);                   // adds person to the vector "people"
}

void User::Login() {
    string pass;                              // takes the password typed in to check
    string name;                             // takes the username typed in to check

    cout << "Please enter your username: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\nPlease enter your password: ";
    cin >> pass;

    for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {                // iterates in the people vector 

        if (name == username[i] && pass == password[i]) {    // look for a match with name and pass

            cout << "Welcome " << username[i] << "! Your email is: " << email[i];  // prints "Welcome "username"! Your email is: "email" 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Login` is a non-static member function of a `User` object, not a stand-alone function. You call it something like `User my_user; my_user.Login();` Perhaps you meant to make it a static function, or a non-member function.

Comment: Please show the exact, word-for-word error in cases like this. That said, your problem is that you're trying to call a "free" function (not within a class) called `Login` and `Register`, but there is no such function. `Login` and `Register` are non-static *member functions* of the `User` class, so you'll need to create a user object before calling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error results from not creating an object of the Class User in your main file.
You could either declare a global User variable:

```
User g_User{};
```

Or a local variable in your main method depends on your use case.

Another solution would be to make Register and Login static in the Class User.

If you choose the object method do something like that:

```
g_User.Register();
```

Comment: Okay this removed this error thanks a lot! but there is still another error about a linker not being found. "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl User::Register(void)" (?Register@User@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main Login and registration system D:\Programming projects\C++\Login and registration system\Login and registration system\Login and registration system.obj 1 
"

Answer (score 0):

Login() and Register() are the members of class "User". If you wanted to use them you have to create an instance of class User. So the better solution should be to make them [static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) or [friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) functions. (Please note that you are accepting the 'status' during startup, if you run the application again, all the user's info will be lost.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "L&S functions.h"
using namespace std;

short status = 1; //defined here to avoid compilation error. Modify according to your needs

int main()
{
  if (status == 1) {
    User::Login();   // this shows an error
    cout << "Login";
  }
  else if (status == 2) {
    User::Register();  // this shows an error
    cout << "Register";
  }
}
```

Your header file has to be:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class User {
string username;
string password;
string mail;

public:
   static void Register();
   static void Login();
};
```

Your cpp file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "L&S functions.h"
using namespace std;

vector<User> people; 
void User::Register() 
{
   User person;  

   cout << "Please choose your username: ";
   cin >> person.username;                         // adds username
   cout << "\nPlease set your password: ";
   cin >> person.password;                        // adds password
   cout << "\nPlease set your email: ";
   cin >> person.mail;                           // adds email
   cout << "\nRegistered successfully!";
   people.push_back(person);                   // adds person to the vector "people"
 }

void User::Login() {
   string pass;                              // takes the password typed in to check
   string name;                             // takes the username typed in to check

   cout << "Please enter your username: ";
   cin >> name;
   cout << "\nPlease enter your password: ";
   cin >> pass;

   for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {                // iterates in the people vector 

    if (name == people[i].username && pass == people[i].password)
    {    
      // look for a match with name and pass

         cout << "Welcome " << people[i].username << "! Your email is: " << people[i].mail;  // prints "Welcome "username"! Your email is: "email" 

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help I tried it but it still shows this error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl User::Register(void)" (?Register@User@@SAXXZ) referenced in function main Login and registration system D:\Programming projects\C++\Login and registration system\Login and registration system\Login and registration system.obj 1 
"

Comment: Is your L&S functions.h and L&S functions.cpp in a different project?

Comment: No they're in the same project.

Comment: I have created the project for you, please try it

Comment: I ran the code and it gives me the same error